# c# Google.Apis.Gmail GmailService delete message

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I have problem with delete message from gmail server using google.apis

I can login and read messages but when I use

```
GmailService.Users.Messages.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.Id);
GmailService.Users.Threads.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.ThreadId);
```

i only delete message 'localy' in instance GmailService. When I repeat checking mail, messagess still they are...
email.Id and email.ThreadId are ok, I can read messages.

I have fully rights. When I loading .json (first clean run) to authorize, gmail give me a full access.
"Read, compose, send and permanently delete all emails from Gmail."

Any ideas? Some code..

```
private static readonly string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom};

....

 GmailService GmailService = new();               
            using (FileStream stream = new("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                                    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                                  credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");
                    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "ma-email@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    this.GmailService = new(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "AppName"
            });

            }
...

UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest inboxlistRequest = GmailService.Users.Messages.List("my-email@gmail.com");
            inboxlistRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
            inboxlistRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
ListMessagesResponse EmailListResponse = inboxlistRequest.Execute();
```

So i have 'email.Id' and 'email.ThreadId', but why i can't pernamently delete these messagess?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These calls:

```cs
GmailService.Users.Messages.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.Id);
GmailService.Users.Threads.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.ThreadId);
```

... create requests, but don't execute them. Try:

```cs
GmailService.Users.Messages.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.Id).Execute();
GmailService.Users.Threads.Delete("my-email@gmail.com", email.ThreadId).Execute();
```